# Reading cookie from Chrome

Tags: c#, cookies, using

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, coding in C# and I'm trying to read a cookie from Chrome.

I have found the HttpCookie class and have added the statement

"using System.Web;"

in the top of the document, but Visual Studio still doesn't seem to recognize this, so I'm not able to use the classes in the System.Web-namespace.

I'm quite sure there is an easy fix for this, but this kind of problem seems to haunt me :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I may ask a silly question that I would have left as a comment if I had the priledges, sorry if this isn't your answer. Have you got a reference to the System.Web.dll in your project?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I thought writing the "using System.Web;" was enough to be able to access that namespace?

Comment: Just added the reference, and that seems to do it :-)

Comment: When I'm having problems I'd always prefer my answer to be embarrassingly simple than difficult to the point of being demoralising. Glad to hear that solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you? And, yes, System.Web is required when you want to use HttpContext.

```
var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["name_of_cookie"];
```